# Making planar transformers in Altium

Tags: transformer, altium, planar-inductor

Does anyone know of a decent (repeatable) way of making planar transformers/planar inductors in Altium? And if so, how was the experience? Drawing out the tracks and checking trace/space clearance manually is a pain (not to mention unreliable). I should also mention that I would prefer some kind of plugin or script or tool or something, making a custom library part is not what I had in mind, I am looking for something a bit more flexible that would permit quick design changes

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, check out the PlanarTx script [here](https://github.com/Altium-Designer-addons/scripts-libraries/wiki/ProjectHome).  Just run the script and the options should be pretty self-explanatory.  Quite flexible too.

[image: Options Menu for PlanarTx]

[image: Example planar transformer in Altium]

You may need to use a net-tie component (some folks refer to these as "shorts") to name the end terminals to sync up in your schematic, since it's all one piece of copper.

Comment: I'm definitely giving that a go, looks perfect